# $viewContentLoading is not working

Tags: angularjs, controller, load

> I'm trying to log some value before content gets loaded. I'm using $viewContentLoading for this purpose which is getting called inside init function. But, value is not getting logged. Can anyone say what's wrong with my code.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($rootScope, $timeout, $q) {
  function init() {
  $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoading', function(event, viewConfig)
{
  alert("Hello");
  console.log(33)
});
}
init();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think that event is for views loaded with ui-router only.. and you are trying in normal one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I mean is that this is how it currently works. To recap:

`$viewContentLoading` gets broadcasted
Dependencies under the resolve section are resolved
Controller gets instantiated and resolve dependencies injected.
$viewContentLoaded is emitted.
The controller reacts to $viewContentLoaded (when it is setup as the delegate to dispatch those events of course).
I've got some views that take a little while to load the data from the server (sometimes ~1 second), so I wanted to show a loading indicator while transitioning from one route to another.

I'm aware of other ways to render it while loading the data. But if routes are responsible of defining the UI state by putting together the controller, template, and data coming from the resolve section, I find it natural to let them notify whoever wants to listen it to it about the current status of the loading process.

My use case

My use case is a Master-Detail view drilldown interaction. Let's say I've got the following ui-views set up. The detail view is a child of the collection view rendering user names in this case.

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| user 1 |  user 1 details view          | 
| user 2 |                               | 
| user 3 |                               | 
| user 4 |                               | 
| user 5 |                               | 
| user 6 |                               | 
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Maybe I'm missing something, but when I first point the browser #/users/1 ideally I'd expect the following to happen:

users parent route resolves the promises and injects the result on the controller associated to that state.
The Collection View gets rendered while users.show is still idle getting data from the sever (this is the API call that sometimes takes up to a second to load).
The detail view renders a loading indicator.
The resolve section in users.show finally gets a 200 OK from the server, injects the dependencies in the controller.
So I can finally render the user's detail.[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/66tLGy?p=preview)